# Prepping comma delimited string for mysql's WHERE IN

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, string

I have the following string...

1,2,3,4,5,6

I want to have this like

'1','2','3','4','5','6'

To use in MySQL's WHERE IN ()

Would anyone know the best way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: It's not necessary to encapsulate values in single quotes.  MySQL will implicitly convert INTegers to VARCHAR and vice versa based on what the column data type is.  Shouldn't be wrapping in single quotes at all if the data type is INT...

Comment: But this argument works the other way round, too, like "You don't have to make assumptions about the type in your script if you pass parameters as strings; MySQL will implicitly convert types were applicable"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [explode](http://php.net/explode) and [implode](http://php.net/implode):

```
 $str = "1,2,3,4,5,6";
 echo "'" . implode("','", explode(',', $str)) . "'";

 //output: '1','2','3','4','5','6'
```

Comment: In case you don't use a parametrized query: If you pass the items as string literals you should treat them as such. You either know that the input string contains only numbers, in which case OMG Ponies's critique applies, or you don't know what the string contains and you have to treat each single item with the appropriate escape function.

Comment: @VolkerK, I agree. Here I have just provided the strict solution to the question leaving the other `MySQL` implementations to the user.

Answer (score 0):

You could [`explode`](https://www.php.net/explode) your string into an array, and then [`join`](https://www.php.net/join) (or [`implode`](https://www.php.net/implode), it's an alias!) it with the quotes:

```
$str = '1,2,3,4,5,6';
$arr = explode(",", $str); // turns your string into array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);
$joined_arr = join("', '", $arr); // becomes 1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6
$query = "... WHERE ... IN ('$joined_arr')"; // note the two missing quotes have been added in
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE (SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(cocodes,cash_out_code,-1),1,1)=','OR...
```

its actually a combination of string functions.. just try in that direction